# tracer.run('main()') report nameError

Tags: python-3.x

I am reading https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/trace.html and got the demonstrating example of

```
import sys
import trace

# create a Trace object, telling it what to ignore, and whether to
# do tracing or line-counting or both.
tracer = trace.Trace(
    ignoredirs=[sys.prefix, sys.exec_prefix],
    trace=0,
    count=1)

# run the new command using the given tracer
tracer.run('main()')

# make a report, placing output in the current directory
r = tracer.results()
r.write_results(show_missing=True, coverdir=".")
```

Run it and get error

```
 NameError: name 'main' is not defined
```

What's the purpose of such a dummy  stupid example?

Comment: Did you create the `main()` function?

Comment: ty. got it but smelly and funny  example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a function named main in order for the example to work. In the example you are tracing the execution of the function main() so it needs to be present for you to run the example successfully